# Получение данных Firebase

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase, firebase-database, firebase-android

Есть база данных с категориями, каждая категория внутри имеет список значений. Как мне сделать,чтобы при выборе категории, выводился список элементов,которые входят в выбранную категорию ? Сейчас у меня выводятся названия категорий, использую RеcyclerView.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               // Iterable<DataSnapshot> ProductChild = dataSnapshot1.getChildren();

                ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
                p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                list.add(p);


            }
            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

К примеру, человек выбирает категорию "Молочные продукты". И мне надо,чтобы в этом же Activity отобразился список продуктов, входящих в выбранную категорию. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е мне надо обработать нажатие и как-то сравнивать? Подскажите пожалуйста, т.к. новичок, только изучать начал Android и первый раз работаю с Firebase.

Абстрактный класс обработки нажатия на категорию:

```
public abstract class RecyclerClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;// используется, чтобы понять, произошел клик
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener =
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        };

public RecyclerClickListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        View clickedChild = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY()); // findChildViewUnder используется для определения нажатого элемента
        if (clickedChild != null && !clickedChild.dispatchTouchEvent(e)) {
            int clickedPosition = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(clickedChild); // getChildAdapterPosition - определение позиции
            if (clickedPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                onItemClick(rv, clickedChild, clickedPosition);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

public abstract void onItemClick(RecyclerView recyclerView, View itemView, int position);}
```

На данный момент мне выводится список с категориями продуктов : Молочные продукты, рыба,мясо и т.д.

```
public class ProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<ProductModel>list;
private ProductAdapter adapter;

private DatabaseReference reference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClickListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(RecyclerView recyclerView, View itemView, final int position) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductSelectionActivity.this, "Click" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

        }
    });


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
                p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                list.add(p);


            }
            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductSelectionActivity.this, "Ooops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}}
```

А теперь мне нужно,чтобы после нажатия на категорию открывался список с продуктами данной категории. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
Map<String, Object> newPost = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : newPost.entrySet()) {
      CategoryMain= entry.getKey(); // наполняйте тут лист с главными категориями
      Map<String, Object> newPost4 = (Map<String, Object>) entry.getValue();
        //придумайте как связать главную директорию с дочерней, тот же самый hashmap в помощь
        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry2 : newPost4.entrySet()) {
             Map<Object, Object> properties = (Map<Object, Object>) entry.getValue();
               subCategory = properties.get("Name").toString(); // тут наполняйте лист подкатегорий
        }
        someList.add(new SomeClass(subCategory ));
    }
```

А еще лучше - использовать Firestore

Comment: А можно данный код написать, используя DataSnapshot?

Comment: так уже данные получены в dataSnapshot.getValue(); у вас там может быть любой листенер

Comment: Я сделал абстрактный класс для обработки нажатия на категорию,  затем в главном классе прописал слушатель addOnItemTouchListener, и т.е. в методе OnItemClick я по идее должен прописать код с DataSnapshot, чтобы мне выводился нужный список. Я правильно думаю ? Ссылался на данную информацию: http://blog.pawpaw.mobi/2015/03/onitemclicklistener-recyclerview.html

Comment: покажите код, дополните ваш вопрос

Comment: дополнил вопрос

Comment: я подсказал вам идею, добавил несколько коментов.

Comment: Я это должен прописать в onItemClick ? или где ?