# Firebase RecyclerView OnItemTouchListener

Tags: android, recyclerview, firebase, firebase-database

Есть база данных с категориями, каждая категория внутри имеет список значений. Как мне сделать,чтобы при выборе категории, выводился список элементов,которые входят в выбранную категорию ? Сейчас у меня выводятся названия категорий, использую RеcyclerView.

```
reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               // Iterable<DataSnapshot> ProductChild = dataSnapshot1.getChildren();

                ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
                p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                list.add(p);


            }
            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }
```

К примеру, человек выбирает категорию "Молочные продукты". И мне надо,чтобы отобразился список продуктов, входящих в выбранную категорию.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е мне надо обработать нажатие и как-то сравнивать? Подскажите пожалуйста, т.к. новичок, только изучать начал Android и первый раз работаю с Firebase.

Абстрактный класс обработки нажатия на категорию:

```
public abstract class RecyclerClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener{

private GestureDetector gestureDetector;// используется, чтобы понять, произошел клик
private GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener =
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }
        };

public RecyclerClickListener(Context context) {
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, gestureListener);
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    if (gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        View clickedChild = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY()); // findChildViewUnder используется для определения нажатого элемента
        if (clickedChild != null && !clickedChild.dispatchTouchEvent(e)) {
            int clickedPosition = rv.getChildAdapterPosition(clickedChild); // getChildAdapterPosition - определение позиции
            if (clickedPosition != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                onItemClick(rv, clickedChild, clickedPosition);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
}

public abstract void onItemClick(RecyclerView recyclerView, View itemView, int position);}
```

На данный момент мне выводится список с категориями продуктов : Молочные продукты, рыба,мясо и т.д.

```
public class ProductSelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<ProductModel>list;
private ProductAdapter adapter;

private DatabaseReference reference;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_selection);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.product_list);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerClickListener(this) {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(RecyclerView recyclerView, View itemView, final int position) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductSelectionActivity.this, "Click" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean b) {

        }
    });


    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            list = new ArrayList<ProductModel>();

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                ProductModel p = new ProductModel();
                p.setProductName(dataSnapshot1.getKey());

                list.add(p);


            }
            adapter = new ProductAdapter(ProductSelectionActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(ProductSelectionActivity.this, "Ooops", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}}
```

А теперь мне нужно,чтобы после нажатия на категорию открывался список с продуктами данной категории. Как это сделать?

Comment: По нажатию Передаешь put extra название ключ данной категории вместе с position. На другом фрагменте/активити ловишь это название и втыкаешь в такой же запрос. И зачем так тбрабатывать нажатия, когда можно сделать через интерфейс и все обрабатывать напрямую во фрагменте.

Comment: @Романыч а как именно обрабатывать через интерфейс ?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение данных Firebase](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/915870/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-firebase)

Comment: @IvanVovk мне, как начинающему разработчику, был не очень понятен ваш ответ, поэтому я задал вопрос еще раз.

Comment: Если не очень понятен ответ, то нужно уточнить, а не создавать новый вопрос, где дадут точно такой же не очень понятный ответ.

Comment: @Эникейщик как раз таки здесь дали более развернутый ответ

Answer (score 0):

У вас - 
`FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");`
где `"products"` отдает массив ваших данных json. Почитайте про Firebase примеров в интернете навалом.

про клик:
думаю проще клик обработать вот так: создаете интерфейс

```
public interface ItemClickListener {
void onItemClick(int position);
}
```

потом в адаптере пишете

```
private static ItemClickListener listener;

 void setOnItemClickListener (ItemClickListener listener){
    Adapter.listener = listener;
}
```

а в вашем `ViewHolder`

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Adapter.listener != null){
                    Adapter.listener.onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            }
        });
```

далее идете в свой фрагмент или активность и имплементите ему свой интерфейс

```
Fragment implements ItemClickListener
```

в `OnCreateView` устанавливаете адаптеру слушатель

```
adapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

ну и обрабатываете клик:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(int position) {   

//здесь можно передать аргументы другому фрагменту, но мы просто перейдем в другую активность
        Intent intent = 
new Intent(getActivity()//или this
, DetailActivity.class);
    //для простоты примера можно передать position
//не забывайте она начинается с 0
        intent.putExtra("my_key", position); 

// здесь можно передать list.get(position).getKey() где под этим понимается ключ , который вы передаете,
//например название категории в вашем случае для считывания даных в самой категории
//или это может быть просто нажатая позиция 0, 1, 2 или 3 итд , и там дальше на //другом конце принимаете и вставляете так как вам нужно тут уже думайте сами как вам удобнее*/
            startActivity(intent);
```

А далее в другой активити принимаем эту позицию и по ней выводим свои данные

```
private int position;

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle != null){
            position = bundle.getInt("position");
        }
```

тут мы получили позицию которую нажали и далее по ней устанавливаем свои данные

```
switch (position){
        case 0:
            GetDataFirebase("Бакалея");
            break;
        case 1:
            GetDataFirebase("Гречка");
            break;


    }
```

Дальше String **position** назвал для понимания.

```
 public void GetDataFirebase(String position){
    DatabaseReference DBR = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(position);
```

То есть засовываем название таблицы, далее строим POJO в соответствии со структурой класса "Бакалея" - и выаодим в `RecyclerView`

```
String name итд..геттеры сеттеры.
```

И все. Должно работать.

А еще лучше просто передавать ключ `String` и вставлять его без привязки к позиции. Но тут я просто показал примерный ход действий.

Comment: А в новом активити я добавляю recyclerview и прописываю в классе addValueEventLisneter ? Или нет ?